# Issue with torch.nn.functional.interpolate - Mismatch in Spatial Dimensions

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

Hello StackOverflow community,

I'm encountering an issue while using `torch.nn.functional.interpolate` in my PyTorch code.

Here's a simplified version of the relevant code snippet:

```
def resize_pad(x):
    if x.shape[0] < FRAME_LEN:
        x = torch.nn.functional.pad(x, (0, 0, 0, FRAME_LEN - x.shape[0], 0, 0))
    else:
        x = x.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)  # Add batch and channel dimensions
        x = torch.nn.functional.interpolate(x, size=(1, 1, FRAME_LEN, x.shape[2])).squeeze(0).squeeze(0)
    return x

def pre_process(x):

    x = torch.cat([hand, pose], dim=1)
    x = resize_pad(x)
    print(x.shape)

    x = torch.where(torch.isnan(x), torch.zeros_like(x), x)
    x = x.view(FRAME_LEN, len(LHAND_IDX) + len(LPOSE_IDX))
    return x
```

I'm receiving the following error:

```
ValueError: Input and output must have the same number of spatial dimensions, but got input with spatial dimensions of [300, 5, 3] and output size of (1, 1, 128, 300). Please provide input tensor in (N, C, d1, d2, ...,dK) format and output size in (o1, o2, ...,oK) format.
```

I have a tensor `x` with dimensions [300, 5, 3], and I'm trying to resize it using `interpolate` to achieve an output size of (128, 300).

Comment: please include enough code so we can run it as-is to help you debug. i see 5 variables that need definition before being able to run this